# C# generic call

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to implement something like an EventBus, my classes are:

```
public interface IEventHandler<in T>
{
    void Handle(T event_);
}
```

```
public class SomeEventHandler: IEventHandler<SomeEvent>
{
    public void Handle(SomeEvent event_)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(event_.SomeData);
    }
}

public class SomeEvent
{
    private readonly string _someData;

    public string SomeData { get => _someData; }

    public SomeEvent(string someData)
    {
        _someData = someData;
    }
}
```

```
public class EventBus
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, object> _handlers = new Dictionary<Type, object>(); // probably the object should be something like IEventHandler<?>

    public void Register<T>(IEventHandler<T> eventHandler)
    {
        _handlers[typeof(T)] = eventHandler;
    }

    public void Handle(object event_) // I want to keep this Handle interface as (object event_) (without any <T>)
    {
        var eventType = event_.GetType();
        var eventHandler = _handlers[eventType];
        eventHandler.Handle(event_); // this will not work
    }
}
```

And the expected usage:

```
var eventBus = new EventBus();
eventBus.Register(new SomeEventHandler());
eventBus.Handle(new SomeEvent("some data"));
```

Obviously the EventBus isn't working because I have to store the type or cast the event / event handler before calling the Handle

Any clue?

Thanks!

Comment: So whats the problem?

Comment: I have to do some kind of cast to the Event/EventHandler, but I don't know the correct way to do it

Comment: What is the error? is there any exception . Provide exception. I would prefer to use some DI like autofac

Comment: The problem is that I have to cast it in some why which I don't know. Probably I can do something like:             var method = eventHandler.GetType().GetMethod("Handle");
            var result = method.Invoke(eventHandler, new[]{event_});
but probably there are better ways. This is what I'm asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dynamic` in an environment where you could be pumping events fairly rapidly will likely involve too much overhead.

Instead of keeping a lookup of handler objects, keep a lookup of handler delegates.

Further explanation is within the code that follows.

```cs
public class EventBus
{
    // Change the type of values to Action<object>
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Action<object>> _handlers = new Dictionary<Type, Action<object>>();

    public void Register<T>(IEventHandler<T> eventHandler)
    {
        // When you store the lookup, create the handler.
        _handlers[typeof(T)] = CreateHandler(eventHandler);
    }

    private Action<object> CreateHandler<T>(IEventHandler<T> eventHandler)
    {
        // The lambda that's created here is an Action<object> and the cast assumes that
        // someData is of the correct type.
        return someData => eventHandler.Handle((T)someData);
    }

    public void Handle(object @event)
    {
        var eventType = @event.GetType();
        var eventHandler = _handlers[eventType];

        // The dictionary gives back an Action<object> that you can call directly.
        eventHandler(@event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the problem you have is that this line `var eventType = event_.GetType();` `var` is the type `Type`  which does not contains a method called `Handle`

so what you have to do is change the `public void Handle(object event_)` for `dynamic` like

```
public void Handle(dynamic event_) 
{
    var eventType = event_.GetType();
    var eventHandler = _handlers[eventType];
    eventHandler.Handle(event_); // this will work
}
```

fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/UrnCv5